# How do I solve this memory usage limited problem?

Tags: migrations

I have more than 100,000 articles to move from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

How do I solve this memory usage limited problem?

module: migrate d2d

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently migrate module does not support batch query for to get value of nodes. You need to apply one [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2296187) which work for you.

Comment: Where are these two patch file located? 2296187-10_2.5backport-do-not-test.patch and 2296187_09-batched_query_support.patch. Do I need to rename them?

Comment: you need to apply patch using git